# Google Maps iOS Marker Displaying Title on Touch

Tags: objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have some code right now in my app that displays an application, on touch it will store the location of the marker touched and will animate to that markers position. I have a title for each marker (which I will use down the line to access information for the marker ID via a database).

When I touch the markers with the titles it is displayed above the marker in a white box which I cannot get rid of. I can't seem to find any information online about this and I don't have anything in my code to create the white box. I will paste the code below.

Thanks.

```
- (BOOL)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapMarker:(GMSMarker *)myMarker {
   // NSString* title = myMarker.title;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = myMarker.position;
    latitude2 = coord.latitude;
    longitude2 = coord.longitude;
    [mapView animateToZoom:20];
}

-(void)addMyLocationMarker
{
    mapIcon = @"smallmapicon";
    myMarker.map = nil;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordi = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(myLatitude,myLongitude);
    myMarker=[GMSMarker markerWithPosition:coordi];
    myMarker.map = self.mapView;
    myMarker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;
    myMarker.title = @"Test";
    UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:mapIcon];
    CGSize sacleSize = CGSizeMake(55, 55);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(sacleSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, sacleSize.width, sacleSize.height)];
    UIImage * resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    myMarker.icon = resizedImage;
    NSLog(@"movement");

}
```

Comment: So you don't need that title?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to open Info window then set below property:

```
mapView.selectedMarker = nil;
```

Like,

```
- (BOOL)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapMarker:(GMSMarker *)myMarker {

//set selectedMarker to nil on Mapview

mapView.selectedMarker = nil;

}
```